# Range of numbers repeating in an array matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I have range of numbers repeating in an array in MATLAB for certain number of times?

For instance, if I want the range of numbers from 1:5 repeated 100 times all stored in one array; what is the code for it?

A = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,........]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`repmat`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to repeat vectors or matrices.

```
N=5
M=100
A=repmat(1:N,1,M)
```